# LayoutTransform / ScaleTransform in Avalonia?

Tags: c#, .net-core, avaloniaui, avalonia

What's the equivalent of LayoutTransform in Avalonia?

```
<Slider.LayoutTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.7" ScaleX="0.7" />
</Slider.LayoutTransform>
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to what kekekeks alluded to in his comment, the desired tag is wrapped by the the layout transform in axaml:

```
<LayoutTransformControl>
        <LayoutTransformControl.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
        </LayoutTransformControl.LayoutTransform>
    <TextBlock Text="Scaled" />
</LayoutTransformControl>
```

Or in code behind:

```
var textBlock = new TextBlock { Text = "Inner text" };
var layoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(0.7, 0.7);
        
var layoutTransformControl = new LayoutTransformControl
{
   LayoutTransform = layoutTransform,
   Child = textBlock
};
```

Avalonia LayoutTransformControl docs: [LayoutTransformControl](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/layouttransformcontrol)

Answer (score 1):

Layout transforms are implemented via a separate `LayoutTransformControl` container. Use it as a wrapper.

Comment: I did see that class but it's undocumented and I couldn't figure out how to use it. There's no "scale" in it.

Comment: It works like LayoutTransform in WPF, just provide it with an appropriate transform.